# How to make TFS and ASP.NET Publish consistent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, web-deployment

Is there a good practice or set of methods for making what gets published through web deploy features to be consistent with what gets put in TFS?  I keep getting push back on not keeping things pristine?  Basically my main question is this possible or should I just drop the web publish feature all together as not being compatible with existing methods of pushing to another environment?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.6 or below for my current projects and haven't started with the new build techniques in .NET 5 yet. So I'm more interested in this area than in the new ways to keep things consistent.

Examples of files that are inconsistent are following:

```
1. excluded files
2. excluded directories
3. refresh files
4. other project folders, solution folders
5. suo or user specific files
6. nuget packages
7. iis specific files
8. web.config files
9. app.config files
10. json setting files
11. bin folder, app_code folder, and app_data folder
```

Also in the Web Publish feature it generates an xml based files with options to add exclude files and directories and also ignore publishing certain files by default like the suo files.

The reason I want this is because I want to keep using the web publish feature for its convenience but not have to loose out on the ability or capability to transfer my project to a secondary source who hasn't bought in to the web publish or web deploy features so they just copy and paste the entire project over verbatim from TFS.

Answer (score 1):

What we store in source is always different from what we deploy.  We use WebDeploy extensively for 40+ products with great success.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective.  I wish I had the option to separate web deployment from my web project completely in a separate project or some kind of master deployment solution in visual studio.  Maybe I should just use git then publish to the tfs directory as well as my other environments...